# Rails 5 - wkhtmltopdf does not include bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, wkhtmltopdf

**Problem** - wkhtmltopdf does not include my Bootstrap styles when generating displaying the PDF. I have tried numerous methods from all over the interwebs with no luck.

**System Specs**

- Rails 5.1.4
- ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]

Here are the snippets of code:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

# app/controllers/forms_controller
def show
  @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "#{@form.id}",
        template: 'forms/show.html.erb',
        locals: { f: @f }
    end
  end
end

# app/views/forms/show.html.erb
<%= render 'forms/form.html.erb' %>
```

Comment: Did you include `stylesheet_link_tag` and `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` in `form.html.erb` as described in the `wicked_pdf` docs?

Comment: @jvillian - If I am using the bootstrap-sass gem, where are my bootstrap stylesheets located?

Comment: I do this to include bootstrap: `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css"`. I don't recall if there was further configuration.

Comment: BTW, if you're deploying on Heroku, you'll want to use `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'` unless you want `wkhtmltopdf-binary` to instantaneously suck up all available memory in the known universe.

Comment: @jvillian - Thank you for letting me know about that gem. I would've totally pushed `wkhtmltopdf-binary` to heroku. On the other hand, I took your advice and put the `<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>` in the header of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Unfortunately, nothing is changing.

Comment: I'll start an answer and see if we can't sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

`form.html.erb` should have something like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("form_stylesheet") %> 
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css", media: "all" %>
```

I included a line there for including Fontawesome fonts - just so you could see that bit.

Then, in your `form_stylesheet.sass` (which should be located in `app/assets/stylesheets`), you should have something like:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets'
@import 'bootstrap'
@import 'some_other_styling'
```

NOTES:

- I'm using `sass` as my css preprocessor. If you're using straight css or scss, then you'll need to modify as appropriate.
- 'some_other_styling' is where you can put additional css rules. If you don't have any, then don't include that line.

All that seems to work for me...

Oh, and in `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`, I have:

```
WickedPdf.config ||= {}
WickedPdf.config.merge!({
  # your extra configurations here
})

def wicked_pdf_asset(*sources)
  sources.collect { |source|
    asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{source}.sass")

    if asset.nil?
      #raise "could not find asset for #{source}.css"
    else
      "<style type='text/css'>#{asset.body}</style>"
    end
  }.join("\n").gsub(/url\(['"](.+)['"]\)(.+)/,%[url("#{wicked_pdf_image_location("\\1")}")\\2]).html_safe
end
```

I don't recall if that helped me sort things out.

Comment: Thank you for posting that solution. However, prior to reading this, I've found a Git Repository that I looked around and figured it out! https://github.com/eltonsantos/wicked_pdf_example

Comment: Great news! Was the answer in anything I posted? If not, perhaps you could add your own answer so that future readers can see how you solved it without having to scrounge through the git repository.

Comment: You indirectly pointed me in the right direction so I knew how to search 'smarter' in Google! I'll post the solution a little later today :)

Comment: would totally love to see what you added @JeffreyWen